# What does "Expression list of the form (a; b; c) is not supported in this context" mean?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am getting the error "Expression list of the form (a; b; c) is not supported in this context" when compiling a report, after removing some fields and adding a few new ones. This prevents the report from being compiled.

I am using iReport 5.1.0.

The full error is as follows:

> Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@19c51d5  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: calculator_Events_1383802163165_797769: 325: Expression list of the form (a; b; c) is not supported in this context. at line: 325 column: 21. File: calculator_Events_1383802163165_797769 @ line 325, column 21. 1 error      at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:113)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:240)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:156)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:439)     at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:528)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: calculator_Events_1383802163165_797769: 325: Expression list of the form (a; b; c) is not supported in this context. at line: 325 column: 21. File: calculator_Events_1383802163165_797769 @ line 325, column 21. 1 error      at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)     at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:915)     at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:564)     at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:540)     at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)     at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:109)     ... 7 more

As requested, the jrxml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Events" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="81b33856-d23f-41e3-99a1-9ec1f42e7781">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.6105100000000008"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<style name="Title" fontName="Arial" fontSize="40" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
<style name="Column Heading" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="14" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
<style name="Field Label" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
<style name="Detail" fill="Solid" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Arial">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="timedateStart" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="timedateEnd" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="timedateReported" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="areaStart" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="areaEnd" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="login" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="state" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="summary" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="details" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripInvolvement" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="itsrClass" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="closeoutComments" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripFrom" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripTo" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripDelay" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="eventNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tripOperator" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="safetyComments" class="java.lang.String"/>
<group name="ID" keepTogether="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="101">
            <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm">
                <reportElement uuid="ccf2faf4-1ebc-4833-bffb-be793843bfbb" style="Detail" x="89" y="29" width="95" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{timedateStart}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="bc927ec0-afbe-4acb-a2dd-30ed83bf87ca" style="Field Label" x="0" y="29" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Start Time:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="ca7ec72f-66dc-48ee-a3ba-1a8ad24e5151" style="Detail" x="273" y="29" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{timedateEnd}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e4b8515a-e1f4-46a2-b539-609918c274e8" style="Field Label" x="184" y="29" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[End Time:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="b77e01cd-299d-4de2-8087-c2a39dfad2c1" style="Detail" x="273" y="11" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{areaStart}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="8c7e8a18-8bc1-4458-a8ba-b08289f93d1f" style="Field Label" x="184" y="11" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Start Location:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f70f1a2a-c8b9-49b8-b89c-e316c0f3d5a9" style="Detail" x="651" y="11" width="151" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{login}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f66e357d-4951-4bbb-8c5a-7ef6620f2146" style="Field Label" x="562" y="11" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[User:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="62f6ee8e-2f53-4790-abc8-3eb18e0fc373" style="Detail" x="462" y="11" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{areaEnd}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="608c4c23-f157-4e67-8e3e-2d5e61b973da" style="Field Label" x="373" y="11" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[End Location:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="4e78d65d-579f-46d6-88a9-d32ad8c65603" style="Detail" x="651" y="29" width="151" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{state}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="df4c04ba-02b1-4a5a-85fe-73d696ed4baf" style="Field Label" x="562" y="29" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[State:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5116325d-bfec-4937-a839-fcaf57ac91f3" style="Detail" x="89" y="65" width="714" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{summary}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b98c7a80-a12c-4868-8e02-e075a156b085" style="Field Label" x="0" y="65" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Title:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="8e708653-5838-4046-a081-92035aa855fe" style="Detail" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="89" y="83" width="714" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{details}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="adc7448c-13a8-4911-b7b6-74e7b9261d7e" style="Field Label" x="0" y="83" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Details:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="aa3bc766-6000-47f2-8e65-da927940c456" style="Detail" x="462" y="29" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{timedateReported}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="72920f21-de19-4494-bbe9-38ae43e263a2" style="Field Label" x="373" y="29" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Report Time:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="13211da9-beb1-415c-ac7f-5389686ef661" x="0" y="5" width="802" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="5.75" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ad7bdabe-7f4b-4b72-b99d-6fe18afac7c0" style="Field Label" x="0" y="11" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Event Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="2148ce11-9119-48e8-8c91-002a7107fbcb" style="Detail" x="89" y="11" width="95" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{eventNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="39bff358-7af5-4752-bfc4-f803bfadab40" style="Field Label" x="0" y="47" width="89" height="18">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{code} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Code:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="9730d29d-873b-4d29-b028-48404027e19b" style="Detail" x="89" y="47" width="95" height="18">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{code} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="64">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{itsrClass} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="10f8cca4-d383-4ba1-9cf4-8795b1b0dd98" style="Field Label" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="6" width="183" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="ID"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="15"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Categorisation]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="cfaee340-8abf-4197-8c08-10b10ef66dcf" style="Field Label" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="26" width="115" height="18" printWhenGroupChanges="ID"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ITSR Classification:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="78403c7e-1d15-4eea-aeca-cc401fbad57a" style="Field Label" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="44" width="115" height="18" printWhenGroupChanges="ID"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Safety Comments:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b1edd0e3-7c49-4838-8fc8-6d699873ba85" style="Detail" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="117" y="26" width="684" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itsrClass}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="b6973a40-0464-410a-9fa5-b3b814e36a31" style="Detail" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="117" y="44" width="684" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{safetyComments}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="5a3a0871-0b2b-4b8d-945b-755259a29f38" x="0" y="3" width="802" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
        <band height="20">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{closeoutComments} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="23b26dc6-d74b-45f5-b4f6-c91ca98613b0" style="Field Label" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="0" width="115" height="18" printWhenGroupChanges="ID"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Closeout:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="91479638-455b-4e46-a6f4-b3dd9d4dc2a8" style="Detail" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="117" y="0" width="684" height="18"/>
                <textElement>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{closeoutComments}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="Trip">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripInvolvement}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripInvolvement} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1edf4f6a-4acb-4f8f-ac70-f1a3c754567e" style="Field Label" x="89" y="2" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Train]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1f5c9a4e-c5bf-4d27-9f0c-21a42a65ecef" style="Field Label" x="178" y="2" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1a8a189c-a27e-4ca5-b148-11ed220b2584" style="Field Label" x="515" y="2" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[From]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="48030e71-fe77-4c61-a106-018c90e536a6" style="Field Label" x="603" y="2" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[To]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9c3b0468-afb7-4d7a-be92-db117bc397b2" style="Field Label" x="702" y="2" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Delay]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f4afaf65-7726-4f41-9959-ab9ac23e38a5" style="Detail" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="2" width="89" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripInvolvement} != null ? ( $F{tripInvolvement}.equals( "primary" ) ? "Primary" : "Reactionary" ) : null]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="7017fd47-578c-4e81-b10f-e2958e53acd8" style="Field Label" x="277" y="2" width="239" height="18"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Operator]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="fa1ceb36-94f4-4663-a93d-238d17090a6c" x="1" y="0" width="801" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="ID Group Footer Response">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="62" splitType="Stretch">
        <image isUsingCache="true">
            <reportElement uuid="1da1169f-b408-446a-bb59-54c6c8fd916b" x="0" y="0" width="222" height="60"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["client_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="80d953b0-4a59-4da5-8a65-b837b70c5f00" style="Title" x="184" y="0" width="618" height="60"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Event Report]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="1" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement uuid="65b62c3c-1b80-498e-94d5-892b9c188550" positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="1"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="19" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="d2773154-ce1e-4234-bfd3-c7230b1e1cbe" style="Detail" x="89" y="0" width="89" height="18">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripName} != null;]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="a577c389-9b30-439e-bb16-119f8221c87d" style="Detail" x="178" y="0" width="100" height="18">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripDate} != null;]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="134f90c3-b3b3-4007-8040-c91db462be10" style="Detail" x="515" y="0" width="89" height="18">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripFrom} != null;]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripFrom}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="b3648125-f342-4539-ac36-22cfa152c92d" style="Detail" x="603" y="0" width="100" height="18">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripTo} != null;]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripTo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="536f9148-1de2-428b-aa8a-9bdb4488cba3" style="Detail" x="702" y="0" width="89" height="18">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripDelay} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripDelay}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd MMM yy HH:mm" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="b138c7d9-c31c-4c9d-b004-d343ac194448" style="Detail" x="277" y="0" width="239" height="18">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripFrom} != null;]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tripOperator}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement uuid="e73fa5db-7501-44f9-b061-ba0179add4cd" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF"/>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="d32aa440-7736-464d-b9ca-4b5ff2c86929" style="Field Label" x="762" y="0" width="40" height="24" forecolor="#736343"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="590794dc-150e-4555-941c-6e9742bc4fd2" style="Field Label" x="682" y="0" width="80" height="24" forecolor="#736343"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="4ab75820-1c6a-49de-b76c-272860dc4f7c" style="Field Label" x="0" y="0" width="197" height="24" forecolor="#736343"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image hAlign="Center">
                <reportElement uuid="8dd54fe0-9404-400c-879f-8e5b56d9d839" x="355" y="0" width="96" height="24"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["4tel_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: post your jrxml code.

Comment: Do you have a list or collection parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `$F{tripFrom} != null;` -> `;` is not allowed in groovy there is not such a usage

either remove semicolons from all your `expression`s and `printwhenexpression`s  or

change your report Language from groovy to java

it worked for me

[image]

Comment: Strange, every other report I've made I've left the language as Groovy. Seems to work though.

Comment: :) it looks like there is a java specific type in your report

Comment: if it worked you might want to accept the answer in stackoverflow as well

Comment: Which type is Java specific? All I did was add a few new String fields to a report that used to compile, and then it didn't.

Comment: I added the reason to the answer

Comment: Excellent. Removing the semicolons fixed it. Strange that that wasn't the part of the report I edited though!

Comment: thanks :) .actually if you put ;  in some expression using expression editor(in iReport) it will warn you about the error. "invalid character ... something" for groovy. didn't you see it?

Comment: Possibly. It was over a year ago when I first made the report, and those expressions have always been in there. It's only caused a problem now that I needed to update it. Yet another thing to file under "should never have worked, but did."